# getting rid of the recursion in __getattribute__

Tags: python

It is perfectly explained in the standards [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) saying that:

> In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its
> implementation should always call the base class method with the same
> name to access any attributes it needs, for example,
> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.

Therefore, I wrote a code following what the standard says:

```
class Sample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -10
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'a':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
            
        raise AttributeError()
    
s = Sample()
result = s.a
print(result)
```

I did not fall into recursion, and the output was

```
-10
```

I used here `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` cause the base class of Sample is object.

If I derive the Sample class from another class such as `A`, I should change `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` to `A.__getattribute__(self, name)` as the base class of `class Sample` is `class A`.

```
class A:
    pass

class Sample(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -10
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'a':
            return A.__getattribute__(self, name)
            
        raise AttributeError()
    
s = Sample()

result = s.a
print(result)
```

which gives the same output as expected. No recursion and `-10`.

However, when I try the code without deriving from a class`:

```
class AnyClassNoRelation:
    pass

class Sample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -10
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'a':
            return AnyClassNoRelation.__getattribute__(self, name)
            
        raise AttributeError()
    
s = Sample()

result = s.a
print(result)
```

and calling `__getattribute__` via any class (in this example `class AnyClassNoRelation`) instead of `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` as the standard says call using the base class, I get the same output: no recursion and `-10`.

So my question:

How come this is possible (having the same output without using the base class's `__getattribute__`? Although the standards clearly states that  `__getattribute__` should be called from the base class.

> In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its
> implementation should always call the base class method with the same
> name to access any attributes it needs, for example,
> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.
> Literally, I can call `__getattribute__` with anyclass I define and it works just fine. Could you explain me why that happens?

Comment: You can't call it with any class. Try calling it with `Sample` class and see what happens.